# Django Stripe Fake Card Causes TemplateDoesNotExist Error

Tags: javascript, python, django, stripe-payments

When a person tries to submit a fake credit card into my Stripe payment form, I get an error page saying "TemplateDoesNotExist at /memberships/payment/ followed by membership/membership_payment.html". Here is my code:

views.py: https://dpaste.de/8EUX

html files:
https://dpaste.de/2Y37

I need a way to not show that error page and redirect the user back to /memberships/ and display a card decline message instead. However, if a user types in a valid card, that redirect is correct. Otherwise maybe I need a way to validate the card is able to be charged to see if it is a real one before being able to submit the form.

Traceback has been included in the dpaste link.

I am using this github project as a baseline so all files are mostly the same (except for my dpaste code updates):

https://github.com/danialbagheri/video-membership

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your path, you are missing a "s"

It should be "membership**s**/membership_payment.html" but your code uses "membership/membership_payment.html"

Comment: Ah that worked and now I added a way for the template to display the error message but now I am getting "File "/home/mint/video-membership-master/memberships/views.py", line 128, in PaymentView
    stripe.PaymentMethod.attach(payment_method_id,customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id),
TypeError: modify() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
" Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end.

Comment: this happens when after typing the fake card and displaying the error message to the user, then typing in a valid card and submitting.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve it. Here is the code after deleting the comma. stripe.Customer.modify(user_membership.stripe_customer_id,stripe.PaymentMethod.attach(payment_method_id,customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id))

Comment: Stripe says You're passing an API call as an argument to another API call. That doens't really make sense. The attach call should not be inside the modify customer call

Comment: I think I got it to work I re-used the same code that was in the if statement. I will respond again if anything weird comes up in further tests. Thanks for the answer it worked perfectly.

Comment: now when I try the fake card 2 times in a row I get CardError at /memberships/payment/
Request req_hqP5NOZqslAyD5: Your card was declined. Your request was in test mode, but used a non test (live) card. For a list of valid test cards, visit: https://stripe.com/docs/testing.

Comment: I figured it out. Put it in a try catch statement. Thanks for all the help finding my typos.